# Pass conditional statemnt over TCP socket in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp

I am trying to implement a simple client-server module over TCP socket in python3.

Once they have established connection, the clients job will be to send an information or a conditional statement like "if x > 100, then set y=10" to the server.

Server has its own value of x (say 200). While it received the conditional statement from client, it would check x with the statement and continue with y.

The question is, at server this is just a string, and not a statement. Is there any way to convert this string to conditional statement ? Or what can be a good way to do this ?

Comment: Does Python have `eval`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, eval() is working in python. Just one thing to share, while the string has text = 'if x<100' it is not working, but if i do 'x<100' and use :  if eval(text) then it is working.